Combining CPG and LLM for Code summary and understanding
I recently discovered  CODE PROPERTY GRAPHS for CPG generation and The output is compatible with Neo4J. Which got me thinking whether using a LLM on top of the CPG would give better Code Summarization results.
Currently Im experimenting with generating individual File summaries and Uploading them to a ChromaDb
I Installed joern got the CPG and Uploaded to Neo4J, Im not sure what is the best way to query the code?
Do we get an LLM to generate Cyper Queries ?
or
Do we upload the CPG itself as embeddings in the graph db?

Yes, LLM is able to generate cypher queries.  This is a blog (Not my own) where you can get a ton of info on how to do it.  https://medium.com/neo4j/generating-cypher-queries-with-chatgpt-4-on-any-graph-schema-a57d7082a7e7
